# 18.10 Can't send file to iPhone over bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, iphone

I can see my iPhone in the bluetooth devices list, ubuntu and the iphone well paired and was showing connected.  I just cannot get a menu that say 'send file to ..'.  I looked around but have not figure out how to send my file to my iPhone.  Please someone throw me a tip. Thanks!

Comment: If the option isn't shown, that may mean that the phone does not offer the service

Comment: Okay, how to check it on my phone?

Comment: Maybe my iPhone need jailbreak?

Comment: You may just need a bluetooth app that will enable obex